# How to normalize a given property using callback or any other method in Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2

Let's say I have the following response coming from an API call:

```
[
  {
    "AgreementNumber": 20266,
    "StartDate": "2005-07-01T00:00:00",
    "EndDate": "2006-06-30T00:00:00",
    "AgreementTypeId": 1,
    "CfProgramLevelId": 2,
    "TamFlag": 0,
    "ParentAgreementNumber": null,
    "DistributorId": 16,
    "CustomerSiteId": 232,
    "RowId": 100,
    "Source": "Wonderware",
    "ActiveFlg": 1
  },
  ...
]
```

I am mapping that result to a `Agreement` entity as follow:

```
$propertyNameConverter = new PropertyNameConverter();
$encoders              = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];
$normalizers           = [new ObjectNormalizer(null, $propertyNameConverter), new ArrayDenormalizer(),];
$serializer            = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

$entities = $serializer->deserialize($data, "QuoteBundle\\Entity\\Agreement[]", 'json');
```

This is how the entity looks like:

```
class Agreement
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="StartDate", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $startDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="QuoteBundle\Entity\AgreementType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="AgreementTypeID", referencedColumnName="AgreementTypeID")
     */
    private $agreementType;

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $startDate
     */
    public function setStartDate(\DateTime $startDate)
    {
        $this->startDate = $startDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param AgreementType $agreementType
     */
    public function setAgreementType(AgreementType $agreementType)
    {
        $this->agreementType = $agreementType;
    }
}
```

Each time I try to map the data I got the following error:

> Expected argument of type "DateTime", "string" given

And it's fine since I am expecting a `DateTime` as the `startDate`. The solution here is to transform|normalize the data before map it to the entity.

I have read [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#using-callbacks-to-serialize-properties-with-object-instances) but I can't find how to apply this "callback" to a given property since the example is a simple use case and not a complex one.

I have tried the following code:

```
$dateTimeNormalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer();
$dateTimeCallback   = function ($dateTime) {
    return $dateTime instanceof \DateTime ? $dateTime->format(\DateTime::ATOM) : '';
};

$dateTimeNormalizer->setCallbacks(['startDate' => $dateTimeCallback, 'endDate' => $dateTimeCallback]);

$normalizers = [
    new ObjectNormalizer(null, $propertyNameConverter),
    new ArrayDenormalizer(),
    $dateTimeNormalizer,
];

$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
```

But is not working since I am still getting the same error as above. I know there is a [DateTimeNormalizer](http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/DateTimeNormalizer.html) but adding it as a new entry on the `$normalizers` array doesn't make it to work. The result is the same meaning same error as above.

Also I need a callback to normalize the property `AgreementTypeId` as `agreementType` since I am pretty sure it will fails as well. (In fact is not being mapped currently and I think the problem is because a name mismatch)

Can any one help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was few lines below - [Recursive Denormalization and Type Safety](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#recursive-denormalization-and-type-safety)

```
    $encoder = new JsonEncoder();

    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor());
    $serializer = new Serializer(array(new DateTimeNormalizer(), $normalizer, new ArrayDenormalizer()), [$encoder]);

    $entities = $serializer->deserialize($data, "QuoteBundle\\Entity\\Agreement[]", 'json');
```